# Site broken in IE7 - how to look for clues?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-7, http-headers, http-compression

currently working on a site - we enabled compression was in iis6 on friday. also some css / javascript files have been minified...

Now back on monday and it appears the site has stopped working in IE7 and after reverting the changes the site still fails to work in IE7 and IE8.

Does anyone have any tips as to where we can start looking for clues as to where the error is? The page sometimes displays after a refresh but nothing is clickable....

Many thanks

Comment: can you paste a code snippet or something of the changes you made and or a snapshot of the old code while it was working?

Comment: Does IE have an 'error console' or 'javascript console'? Those can sometimes help when things go awry.

Comment: @sarnold IE has 'Dev Tools' which are like a less feture-rich version of Firebug or the webkit Inspector. Another option is to try Firebug Lite http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Comment: If you can't figure it out yourself, post a link to the site if possible. Then, someone can figure it out for you :)

Comment: the site is http://mastermixdigital.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Issue was javascript with the defer="defer" which caused the site to fail, however we tried removing this attribute on javascript files.

However it required that the browser - IE 7 was closed fully reopened before the site worked properly!

hope this helps somone in the future.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. If you mark the answer as "accepted" (even though you answered it yourself), you'll be more likely to help someone in the future. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if there are any JS errors, display dev console (F12) and try to switch between Browser mode and Document Mode, play with HTML doctype (quirks, standards, transient).